# Editing this code to redirect to mobile site on screen size rather than device

Tags: javascript

The question says it all, the below is my current redirect code, but I want to edit it so it redirects on screensize rather then device. It will still need to set the cookie though so users can come back to the main site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mfp_url='http://mob.visitorconversions.co.uk';
var mfp_host_name=document.location.hostname;
var mfp_request_uri=document.location.pathname;
var  mfp_no_mobile=location.search;
var mfp_cookie=document.cookie;

function mf_detect(){var  mfp_ua=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();var mfp_devices=['vnd.wap.xhtml+xml','sony','symbian','nokia','samsung','mobile','windows ce','epoc','opera mini','nitro','j2me','midp-','cldc-','netfront','mot','up.browser','up.link','audiovox','blackberry','ericsson','panasonic','philips','sanyo','sharp','sie-','portalmmm','blazer','avantgo','danger','palm','series60','palmsource','pocketpc','smartp hone','rover','ipaq','au- mic','alcatel','ericy','vodafone','wap1','wap2','teleca','playstation','lge','lg- ','iphone','android','htc','dream','webos','bolt','nintendo'];

for(var i in mfp_devices) {if(mfp_ua.indexOf(mfp_devices[i])!=-1){return true}}}if(mfp_no_mobile!='? nomobile=1'&&mfp_cookie.indexOf('mfp_no_mobile')==-1) {mfp_is_mobile=mf_detect();if(mfp_is_mobile){window.location=mfp_url+"? h="+mfp_host_name+"&r="+mfp_request_uri}}else{if(mfp_cookie.indexOf('mfp_no_mobile')!=-1)  {}else{mfp_cookie_expires=new   Date();mfp_cookie_expires.setTime(mfp_cookie_expires.getTime()+1000*60*60*24);document.cook    ie="mfp_no_mobile=1; expires="+mfp_cookie_expires.toGMTString()+"; path=/;"}}
</script>
```

Using the below answer I now have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mfp_url='http://mob.visitorconversions.co.uk';
var mfp_host_name=document.location.hostname;
var mfp_request_uri=document.location.pathname;
var  mfp_no_mobile=location.search;
var mfp_cookie=document.cookie;

function mf_detect() {
var MOBILE_WIDTH = 640;
var screenWidth = function() {
    width = null;
    if (window.screen != null) width = window.screen.availWidth;
    if (window.innerWidth != null) width = window.innerWidth;
    if (document.body != null) width = document.body.clientWidth;
    return width;
}
return screenWidth() <= MOBILE_WIDTH;
}

for(var i in mfp_devices) {if(mfp_ua.indexOf(mfp_devices[i])!=-1){return true}}}if(mfp_no_mobile!='? nomobile=1'&&mfp_cookie.indexOf('mfp_no_mobile')==-1) {mfp_is_mobile=mf_detect();if(mfp_is_mobile){window.location=mfp_url+"? h="+mfp_host_name+"&r="+mfp_request_uri}}else{if(mfp_cookie.indexOf('mfp_no_mobile')!=-1)  {}else{mfp_cookie_expires=new   Date();mfp_cookie_expires.setTime(mfp_cookie_expires. getTime()+1000*60*60*24);document.cook    ie="mfp_no_mobile=1; expires="+mfp_cookie_expires.toGMTString()+"; path=/;"}}
</script>
```

But it doesn't seem to be redirecting anything!

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. If screen resolution is less than MOBILE_WIDTH, it redirects to http://mob.visitorconversions.co.uk?h=[referring_host]&r=[referring_path]

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tppiotrowski/QyFNB/). You may need to resize the Result window to see the redirect load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var mfp_url = 'http://mob.visitorconversions.co.uk';
    var mfp_host_name = document.location.hostname;
    var mfp_request_uri = document.location.pathname;
    var mfp_no_mobile = location.search;
    var mfp_cookie = document.cookie;

    function mf_detect() {
        var MOBILE_WIDTH = 640;
        var screenWidth = function() {
            width = null;
            if (window.screen != null) width = window.screen.availWidth;
            if (window.innerWidth != null) width = window.innerWidth;
            if (document.body != null) width = document.body.clientWidth;
            return width;
        };
        return screenWidth() <= MOBILE_WIDTH;
    }

    if (mfp_no_mobile != '?nomobile=1' && mfp_cookie.indexOf('mfp_no_mobile') == -1) {
        mfp_is_mobile = mf_detect();
        if (mfp_is_mobile) {
            window.location = mfp_url + "?h=" + mfp_host_name + "&r=" + mfp_request_uri
        }
    } else {
        if (mfp_cookie.indexOf('mfp_no_mobile') != -1) {} else {
            mfp_cookie_expires = new Date();
            mfp_cookie_expires.setTime(mfp_cookie_expires.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
            document.cookie = "mfp_no_mobile=1; expires=" + mfp_cookie_expires.toGMTString() + "; path=/;"
        }
    }​
</script>
```

Comment: I tried that but now it just doesn't redirect anything. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: There are still some errors in your question code, so I posted the complete code snippet to reduce confusion.